# Is there a way to export and download your Angular front-end web page to pdf using back-end nodeJs's pdfmake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, export-to-pdf, pdfmake

I'm trying to export a certain page from my Angular/nodeJs application using "pdfmake" and have it show up as a download option on the same page after having heard that the best way to export pdf's is through the back-end. After reading the guide and following a tutorial, however, the code writes data to my header but doesn't appear to do anything else.

In the past I've tried following the tutorial below and have read through the method documentation of pdfmake.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0910p09D0Sg
https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/getting-started/client-side/methods/

I'm uncertain whether pdfmake is only supposed to be used by 'headless chrome' (of which I don't possess much knowledge) and wonder if my method can work.

I've also tried using the .download() and .open() functions with pdfMake.createPdf() which resulted in errors.

NodeJs code

```
router.post('/pdf', (req, res, next) => {
    var documentDefinition = {
        content: [
            'First paragraph',
            'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
        ]
    }
    const pdfDoc = pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition)
    pdfDoc.getBase64((data) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename="filename.pdf"'
        });
        const download = Buffer.from(data.toString('utf-8'), 'base64');
        res.end(download);
    })
})
```

Angular code

```
savePDF() {
    this.api.post('/bookings/pdf')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

In this case the savePDF() function is called when the user clicks on a button on the web page.

Because nothing was happening upon clicking the button I decided to console.log the result which showed up as a very long string of data.

The pdf document data only contains testdata for now as I was trying to get a download link to work before trying to download the webpage itself.

I can also assure you that there is nothing wrong with the routing and the functions are called properly.

I expected the savePDF() function to start a download of a pdf containing the test data shown in the NodeJs "documentDefinition" content, but the actual result did seemingly nothing.

Comment: I think you are just probably missing the `res.send()` statement. Try `res.send(download); res.end();`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help, instead it throws me a 
new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');

Comment: I've never used pdfMake but phantom-html-to-pdf and maybe I'm missing something. If I were you, I'll try to check other tutorials or examples like in here: https://medium.com/@kainikhil/nodejs-how-to-generate-and-properly-serve-pdf-6835737d118e